# How to fetch data from complex array objects structures?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such an object

```
data: {
      dataFirst: { 
        Food: [ {id: 536131, name: "option1", }]
      },       
      dataSecond: { 
        Autos: [{id: 678, name: 'option1'}],
        Houses: [
          {id: 6876, name: "option1"},
          {id: 6876, name: "Placed App"},
        ],
        Phones: [
          {id: 672, name: "option1"},
          {id: 97249, name: "Placed},
        ],
        Food: [
          {id: 772, name: "option1"},
          {id: 6777, name: "Placed},
        ], 
      }
    }
```

The problem is, that I may have same data in dataFirst and dataSecond, for examle 'Food', I have 2 array objects that contains different data but I need to make it one object 'Food' with the data from 2 of them, from the dataFirst 'Food' and dataSecond 'Food'. I had such a code:

```
export const parser = ({ data }) => {
  const result = Object.values(data).reduce((prev, topicsGroup) => {
    Object.assign(prev, topicsGroup);
    return prev;
  }, {});
  return result;
}
```

but this code doesn't unite 2 'Food' objects but returns data only from the dataFirst 'Food' object wihout second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through all values of your main data object with `Object.values(data)` and combine them with `reduce` by concatenating arrays corresponding to common keys:

```js
let data = {
  dataFirst: {
    Food: [{
      id: 536131,
      name: "option1",
    }]
  },
  dataSecond: {
    Autos: [{
      topicId: 678,
      name: 'option1'
    }],
    Houses: [{
        topicId: 6876,
        name: "option1"
      },
      {
        topicId: 6876,
        topicName: "Placed App"
      },
    ],
    Phones: [{
        topicId: 672,
        name: "option1"
      },
      {
        topicId: 97249,
        name: "Placed"
      },
    ],
    Food: [{
        topicId: 772,
        name: "option1"
      },
      {
        topicId: 6777,
        name: "Placed"
      },
    ],
  }
};


let res = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (k in acc) acc[k] = acc[k].concat(v);
    else acc[k] = v;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```